# MySQL - sort on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a problem that will sort my output by following rules:

if g.grade>8, then

```
order by g.grade asc, s.name asc
```

if g.grade <=8, then

```
order by g.grade desc, s.marks asc
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `case when`:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN g.grade > 8 THEN g.grade ELSE (0 - g.grade) END asc,
         CASE WHEN g.grade > 8 THEN s.name ELSE s.marks END asc
```

Comment: Your second `CASE` expression has a problem.  One branch generates a `varchar` while the other generates a number.  This would not work in most RDBMS, and even if it works in MySQL, it should be avoided.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hmm, you're right, I'm thinking about how to solve this issue.

Comment: I couldn't think of way, but the good news is that your answer probably does work for MySQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen For `MySQL`, it works, I've tested it. But `sql-sever` does not work exactly. Maybe should use dynamic sql for other RDBMS.